# Split string from sentence into newline in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string:

> "Community - Moderate Environment - Minor Financial - Major Health & Safety - Extreme "

I want to split this string into:

`Community - Moderate`

`Environment - Minor`

`Financial - Major`

`Health & Safety - Extreme`

its like give newline after one category,

how do I get that

I try to split:

> var t = Community - Moderate Environment - Minor Financial - Major Health & Safety - Extreme
>
> t.split('-')

after that I don't know what can I do

Comment: `split` creates an array. Do you actually want an array, or just a new string with newlines?

Comment: string with new line

Comment: this is not a question following the stackoverflow guidelines. it does not show an attempt of solving this yourself.

Comment: That's kind of impossible. What should `Word1 - Word2 Word3 Word4 - Word5` split into? It can either be `Word1 - Word2 Word3` and `Word4 - Word5` or `Word1 - Word2` and `Word3 Word4 - Word5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace` instead of `split` to replace the word after a `-` with that word concatenated with a newline:

```js
const str = "Community - Moderate Environment - Minor Financial - Major Health & Safety - Extreme ";
console.log(str.trim().replace(/(- \w+) +/g, '$1\n'));
```

The regular expression

```
/(- \w+) +/
```

captures a dash, followed by a space, followed by word characters, in a group. Then, it matches spaces, so that the whole match can be replaced with the first capture group - effectively replacing the spaces with newline characters.